# Dynamically update pandas column names to avoid code change

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to dynamically update column names that are based on  previous column names? Or what are best practices for column names while processing data? Below I explain the problem:

When processing data, I often need to create columns that are calculated from the previous columns, and I set up the names like below:

```
|STUDENT|GRADE|GRADE_AVG|GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED|GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL
```

The problem is, if I need to make a change in the middle of this data flow [for example, hypothetically, say I needed to scale the grade before taking the average], I would have to rename all the column names that were produced after this point. See below:

```
|STUDENT|GRADE|**GRADE_SCALED**|GRADE_SCALED_AVG|GRADE_SCALED_AVG_FORMATTED|GRADE_SCALED_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL
```

Since the code to calculate each column is based on the previous column names, this process of name changing **in the code** gets really cumbersome, specially for big datasets for which a lot of code has been produced. Any suggestion on how to dynamically update the column names? or best practices on it?

To clarify, an extension of the example:

my code would look like:

```
df[GRADE_AVG] = df[GRADE].apply(something)
df[GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED] = df[GRADE_AVG].apply(something)
df[GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL] = df[GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED].apply(something)
...
... more column names based on the previous one..
...
df[FINAL_SCORE] = df[GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL_REVISED...etc]
```

And then... I need to change GRADE_AVG to GRADE_SCALED_AVG **in the code**. So I will have change those columns names. This is a small example, but when there are a lot of column names based on the previous one, changing the code gets messy.

What I do is to change all the column names in the code, like below (but this gets really impractical), hence my question:

```
df[GRADE_SCALED_AVG] = df[GRADE].apply(something)
df[GRADE_SCALED_AVG_FORMATTED] = df[GRADE_SCALED_AVG].apply(something)
df[GRADE_SCALED_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL] = df[GRADE_SCALED_AVG_FORMATTED].apply(something)
...
... more column names based on the previous one..
...
df[FINAL_SCORE] = df[GRADE_SCALED_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL_REVISED...etc]
```

Comment: you can rename columns like this `df.columns = [x+'_SCALED' for x in df.columns]`. Here you need to change few thing to add `_SCALED` for selected columns only.

Comment: @Poojan, You're gonna be very happy to know that [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html#pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix) exists

Comment: But since the pieces of code to calculate all those columns use the previous column names, I would have to change all the names in the script -> i.e. df['GRADE_AVG'] to df['GRADE_SCALED_AVG'] everywhere it is mentioned in the script. That would more of the focus of the problem.

Comment: @MattR My above comment is just an example. OP wants to append `SCALED` in middle of word. So `add_suffix` not useful in this case. But thats one more function i get to know today. Thanks

Comment: @Kaisar so if you already renamed columns to `GRADE_SCALED` and so on . Why are you still using old names in your code. ? I am confused.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this isn't really a question about renaming colums; it's about how to reuse the same calculations (or functions) on slightly different inputs, and allow for the resulting column names to indicate the various inputs.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, thank you for clarifying my question

Comment: @Poojan, please see my clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say if your columns will start with `GRADE`. You can do this.

```
df.columns = ['GRADE_SCALED_'+ '_'.join(x.split('_')[1:]) if x.startswith('GRADE') else x for x in df.columns]

# sample test case
>>> l = ['abc','GRADE_AVG','GRADE_AVG_TOTAL']
>>> ['GRADE_SCALED_'+ '_'.join(x.split('_')[1:]) if x.startswith('GRADE') else x for x in l]
['abc', 'GRADE_SCALED_AVG', 'GRADE_SCALED_AVG_TOTAL']
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to rename dynamically is with `rename` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
header = '|STUDENT|GRADE|GRADE_AVG|GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED|GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL'
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header.split('|')) # your dataframe
print(df)
# now rename: can take a function or a dictionary as a parameter
df1 = df.rename(lambda x: re.sub('^GRADE', 'GRADE_SCALE', x), axis=1)
print(df1)


#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [, STUDENT, GRADE, GRADE_AVG, GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED, GRADE_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL]
#Index: []
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [, STUDENT, GRADE_SCALE, GRADE_SCALE_AVG, GRADE_SCALE_AVG_FORMATTED, GRADE_SCALE_AVG_FORMATTED_FINAL]
#Index: []
```

However, in your case, I'm not sure this is what you are looking for. Are the AVG and FORMATTED columns generated from GRADE column? Also, is this RENAMING or REPLACING? doesn't the content of the columns change as well?

It seems a more complete description of the problem might help..

Comment: Thanks, please see I made a clarification in the end of the post.